# how to write function within function to save objects as separated csv file?

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, apply

I have a function as follows:

```
v2_city <- 
        function(city_name){
                result <- v2[city == city_name]
                result
}
```

v2_city is a dataset that has columns of "city_name", "offers".
I would like to create a filter function to save the filtered data separated as objects and ultimately save them as csv file.

To do so, I created city names in list and wanted to use the for loop as follows:

```
list <- c(
'Osaka'
,'Paris'
,'Roma'
,'Barcelona'
,'Fukuoka'
,'Hong Kong')

for (item in list){
        x <- v2[item]
}
```

This gives x file filtered as HongKong. How do I save all separate files as objects and then write them into csv within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about?

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

my_dataset = tibble(city = c("Osaka","Paris","Roma","Barcelona","Fukuoka","Hong Kong"), value = 1:6)

cities = c("Osaka","Paris","Roma","Barcelona","Fukuoka","Hong Kong")

for (j in 1:length(cities){
  my_dataset %>% 
    filter(city == cities[[j]]) %>% 
    write_csv(paste0(cities[[j]],".csv"))
}
```

Comment: This works, Thanks! I have a question though, What do I do to save them in global environment as data frame per city if I am not saving them as csv file?

Comment: @silverrain to create data frames per city, you can try replace for loop with the below: `lapply(cities, FUN = function(city){
  assign(city,my_dataset %>% 
           filter(city == cities[[j]]), envir = .GlobalEnv )
})`

Comment: exactly what @shaojl7says, when working with your own functions do this trick `envir = as.environment(1); assign(...something..., envir = envir)`